# Self-close MDBVue modal on setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, settimeout, mdbootstrap

I'm trying to close an MDBVue modal that's shown by default after 1 minute with a setTimeout method. I want to achieve this using MDBVue's "shown" [event](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/modals/events/) feature. The idea is that a timer should start immediately the modal has shown, and fire the closing code after 60 seconds. My modal begins with this:

`<mdb-modal :show="instructionModal" @close="instructionModal = false" frame size="fluid" centered @shown="instructionSeen">`

And I have the following Vue methods to the effect:

```
instructionSeen() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.handleFade()
    }, 60000);
},
handleFade() {
    this.instructionModal = false;
},
```

Nothing happens with this code, not even when I copy the snippet and put it directly in the `@shown`
 attribute. Can someone please help me?

Comment: The modal is meant to be the instruction stage for an exam app.

Comment: I just realized that none of the event attributes work. I tried with `hide` and the same code failed that fired when I injected it in the `@click.native` directive. So the setTimeout is not the issue, although I still don't know what is.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `away` method inside modal component in mdbvue. Did you try to add ref to the component and then run `away` method after timout with such code: `this.$refs.modal.away()`? It should work.